# Is there a library/API like Leaflet available for Starmaps?

Tags: resource-request, star-maps, data-pipeline

#### Some Background

I am working (recreationally) on [R package](https://github.com/benyamindsmith/mapBliss) that allows for users to create custom, print quality, map art that is commonly found on many drop shipping sites. Seeing that there are sites that offer [custom star maps](https://mapsformoments.co.uk/9-star-map?step=design) I am exploring development of a suite of functions that would allow for custom star maps similar to what I've done for world maps.

#### The Question

Does there exist a library similar to [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com) (or is somehow possible with Leaflet) that allows for creation of custom star maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are some APIs that you can use for starmaps like- [Star-Maps](http://www.wikisky.org/api?locale=EN), [Astronomy API](https://docs.astronomyapi.com/endpoints/studio/star-chart)
There are a library in R for this [Celestrial Maps](https://kimnewzealand.github.io/2019/02/21/celestial-maps/)

Comment: This looks great! It does seem like its very RAM intensive by the way its structured. Thank you for sharing!